# How to configure Oracle WebCenter Portal Project so that I can add JavaScript files without having to restart the server?

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf, webcenter

Title pretty much says it all. Your help is greatly appreciated. I'm so happy that I just got the JavaScript to show up in the first place, now only if it actually updated when I changed it, I can actually starting using JavaScript effectively in my portal project.

Help is MUCH appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you running your project from JDeveloper directly its supported just out of box, change your files and reload. Don't forget about browser cache.
2. Use OHS in front of your weblogic server and setup location for serving static files. Update as you do it with regular web server.
3. Quick and dirty (only for debugging/development stage). Embed your script in adf page using `<af:resource>` component.

Comment: Thanks, btw I had to change a property in web.xml to check for file changes, that was it.